# Problem with filtering newsletter subscriptions

Tags: bug, status-completed, newsletter

On the newsletter subscription page, I used the search box to find the English language newsletter. After typing the word "English" into the search box, the only newsletter that was displayed was the one for the English language site. The preview and subscribe buttons were displayed, but when I clicked on the subscribe button, nothing happened.

I was using Chrome. I saw it at 10:50 a.m. EST, on 8/15/11.

Comment: The url was http://stackexchange.com/newsletters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the bug by causing a given search result to appear a second time. For example, if I typed "English" in the [newsletters](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) search box, then cleared the input and typed "English" again, then the "Subscribe" button beside "English Language and Usage" was unclickable.

This was a JavaScript bug, and should be fixed now.